# Call to a member function has() - in my controller service when i try get doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

registered service yml

```
    AbonamentController:
    class:        ed\partnerBundle\Controller\AbonamentController
```

in running controller :

```
        $abonamentCtrl = $this->get('AbonamentController');
    $abonament = $abonamentCtrl->doSomething($kod );
```

in doSomething method i have

```
 $ab = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('edpartnerBundle:SOme')
```

and have error :

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in

vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 198

what i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If the controller is a service, you should not extend the base Controller class. See also [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

But, you should never execute controller inside controllers. You should use actions and routes to communicate with other controller.

Comment: ok thanks. if i want $this->get to get any kind of service in my service what i should to do ?

Comment: That's something you should never ever want to do. Always only inject the services tou want to use. See the Service Container articles of the symfony docs for more information